# Clarification on multiplication from modular exponentiation precompiled contract

Tags: precompiled-contracts

I'm trying to understand what exactly Vitalik means in the following (from [here](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/vbuterin-patch-2/EIPS/bigint_modexp.md)):

> Note that adding precompiles for addition and subtraction is not required, as the in-EVM algorithm is efficient enough, and
>   multiplication can be done through this precompile via `a * b = ((a + b)**2 - (a - b)**2) / 4`.

My understanding is that this is a more efficient way of performing the multiplication, but what exactly is to be passed to the modexp contract in order to achieve multiplication? is it the squaring of (a+b) and (a-b)? And in that case, what should be passed as the modulus value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but what exactly is to be passed to the modexp contract in order to achieve multiplication? is it the squaring of (a+b) and (a-b)?

Yes, exactly that.

To calculate `a * b % m` you call the precompile once to calculate `(a+b)^2 % m` and once more to calculate `(a-b)^2 % m`, then take the difference (adding `m` if necessary to keep everything positive). This gives you `4 * a * b % m`.

To get finally to `a * b % m`, we need to divide by 4, modulo `m`. The "proper" way to do this is to find the multiplicative inverse of 4 with respect to `m` and multiply through by that. This is a bit trickier and it's only possible to do this when m is odd (i.e. co-prime to 4). *[But see note at the end]*

Example, show that `4 * 5 % 7 = 6`

```
(4 + 5)^2 % 7 = 4
(4 - 5)^2 % 7 = 1
4 - 1 = 3
```

So we have `(4 * (4 * 5)) % 7 = 3`.  Modulo 7, 2 is an inverse of 4 (since `(2 * 4) % 7 = 1`). Therefore, multiplying through by two gives finally `(4 * 5) % 7 = 6`, QED.

> And in that case, what should be passed as the modulus value.

The same `m` as you would have passed in to calculate `(a * b) % m`.

---

*Note*

To divide by four using the normal modular approach as above, we need to multiply through by the inverse of 4 with respect to the modulus, `m`. This would give us a recursive problem: to do a multiplication would require that we could do a multiplication.

However, I think there is a short-cut that can be used to divide by 4 modulo `m`.  We divide twice by 2 modulo `m`.

- If `n` is even (and less than `m`), then `n / 2 % m` is just `n / 2` - i.e. shift one bit right.
- If `n` is odd, `n / 2 % m` can be found simply by calculating `(n + m) / 2` *not modulo* (add `n` and `m` and shift right one bit).

So, in the example above `3 / 4 % 7` is found as follows:

```
(3 + 7) / 2 = 5
(5 + 7) / 2 = 6
```

This is the same as we got before by multiplying through by the inverse of 4 with respect to 7 (which is 2).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for this. Where I was going wrong was I was not getting the multiplicative inverse. Perhaps I should request that the document be updated with this information?